# Update database from ADF Table

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I'm coming from ASP.net and I am having trouble understanding how to simply update a database from an ADF table.

How do I commit changes to a table in a database using data entered by user in an ADF Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from .NET you might have to adapt to a stateful business layer, meaning that your changes are kept in Entity Object Cache up until the point you will issue a Commit. Commit button will process the Entity Objects into sql statements like:

```
insert into (..) ....
update () .. set ....
.....
commit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a commit operation from your model layer.
Try following the basic tutorial to see how this is done:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_rich_app/tut_rich_app.html